# How avoid public property?

Tags: kotlin

Here my Kotlin code:

```
class Test1 {
    var name: String? = null
    var isMarried: Boolean = false
}
```

and use it like this:

```
   val test1 = Test1()
   test1.name = "Name1"
   test1.isMarried = true
   System.out.println("name = " + test1.name + ", isMarried = " + test1.isMarried)
```

But I think it's not a good solution because in class `Test1` property (by default) **has public access**.
So as result the properties `name` and `isMarried` **are visible for all app**. It's very bad. It breaks encapsulation.

So to fix this I use the next approach:

```
class Test2 {
    private var name: String? = null
    private var isMarried: Boolean = false

    fun getName(): String? {
        return name
    }

    fun setName(name: String) {
        this.name = name
    }

    fun isMarried(): Boolean {
        return isMarried
    }

    fun setMarried(isMarried: Boolean) {
        this.isMarried = isMarried
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
 val test2 = Test2()
 test2.setName("Name2")
 test2.setMarried(false)
 System.out.println("name = " + test2.getName() + ", isMarried = " + test2.isMarried())
```

As you can see I was created **my custom getter/setter** methods. Also properties `name` and `isMarried` **are private**. As result the app has no direct access to this properties. The app has access to this properties **only via getter/setter methods**.

Is this a correct solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While this is not technically incorrect, it's just unnecessary work. It's important to understand the distinction between Java fields and Kotlin properties. While Java allows you to read and write directly from a field, Kotlin always hides fields behind accessor methods, hence a property is a set of accessor methods with our without a backing field, that the outer code doesn't have access to. By declaring a `var` you're automatically creating a getter, a setter and a backing field. All operations reading or writing into that property will have to call accessor methods, but Kotlin's syntax hides this from you and makes it seem like you're accessing the field directly. To summarize, you're not gaining any extra encapsulation by introducing your own getters and setters - Kotlin's compiler will do it for you by default.

If you're working with Intellij IDEA or Android Studio, there's a way to view Java equivalent of the Kotlin code you're writing. Just reveal the All actions menu with Cmd + Shift + A and type "bytecode", then pick "Show Kotlin bytecode". You'll see a pane that contains the bytecode for your Kotlin, and you have an option to "Decompile", which will eventually show you the Java equivalent. This is incredibly helpful in understanding what exactly the Kotlin compiler generates.

Comment: An important addition is that Kotlin properties can have custom accessors and even then accessing it "looks like a field".

Comment: Do you mean than when I declare a property like this (e.g.): var name: String? = null , it's mean that property "name" is PRIVATE property. Is I'm right?

Comment: @a_subscriber: Yes.  In Kotlin, a property consists of a getter method (and, if mutable, a setter method) of the appropriate visibility, and (if needed) a private backing field.  This means that **the two approaches in the question are equivalent**!  (The major difference is that callers can use the property _syntax_ only in the first one.  But they compile down to just about the same bytecode.)